# Is it possible to access the spring context outside of a spring-boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create a standalone database application which can offer CRUD operations to other applications/modules...

I am aware of the need to create the entities and services used by the application in another artifact since you cannot depend on a spring-boot application alone.

But, can one get the runtime spring-configuration of a spring-boot application? So one can access a service that is deployed on my application?

For best through-put I am looking for a way to use services on a running spring-boot database application on the same JVM in order to minimise overhead...

Comment: In my opinion you should not try to share your beans, instead provide a (REST) API which can be used to do the CRUD operation. Other application could communicate your application using JSON and HTTP.

Comment: One of the applications which is in need of CRUD is an application with a REST API. I am trying to minimise number of APIs and just use the beans...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. 
If you have an application which need database access, why don't they integrate with the database? Why is a database application needed? If you need some additional logic for the database, that is fine to create a service for it, other restful restful apps can communicate with the database using REST as well.
If other apps need to integrate it directly by using the beans (without REST), then you should rather create shared library instead of a separate application.

Comment: If you have x modules integrating with the same database, there is a need to avoid duplication of entities. In order to avoid the overhead of using those entities from different modules, they should not use a REST api... if you create a library, then you have to implement the infrastructure in every module (not a big issue, i was just wondering)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RMI

What you want is technically it is possible using basic Java RMI (remote method invocation), you just register the bean as the implementation instance and share the interface between the two JVMs, either on localhost or even on different machines.

Spring even gives some additional support for this using `RmiProxyFactoryBean`, see [Spring Remoting RMI article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-rmi).

From above article, you can export it, using:

```
@Bean
RmiServiceExporter exporter(CabBookingService implementation) {
  Class<CabBookingService> serviceInterface = CabBookingService.class;
  RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
  exporter.setServiceInterface(serviceInterface);
  exporter.setService(implementation);
  exporter.setServiceName(serviceInterface.getSimpleName());
  exporter.setRegistryPort(1099); 
  return exporter;
}
```

and import it, using:

```
@Bean
RmiProxyFactoryBean service() {
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactory = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
    rmiProxyFactory.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:1099/CabBookingService");
    rmiProxyFactory.setServiceInterface(CabBookingService.class);
    return rmiProxyFactory;
}
```

Then you can use it in your application context based on your interface.

However I would not suggest to share beans like this because it has the same problem RMI has.

### Shared library

Another way to do what you want is to create a shared library that can be included in other projects.

If all the project, which want to use it are Spring Boot application you can create a Spring Boot starter, see [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html).
This way, other applications just have to add the dependency and they already has access to the beans in their application context, as well as the shared domain objects.

If other application use just regular Spring, they can just `@Import` your main configuration class.

If other apps are using Java, but not Spring, you can still use Spring inside, just provide a factory, which creates an internal Spring context.

### REST service

If other applications are not written in Java, your best bet is to expose a REST interface for them to use the database applications.